# Is it possible to use Android resource references in JSON files

Tags: android, json, android-resources

Let's say I have a static file `res/raw/questions.json` with some content like:

```
[
  {
    "text": @string/question_1_text,
    "image": @drawable/question_1_image
  },
  {
    "text": @string/question_2_text,
    "image": @drawable/question_2_image
  },
  ...
]
```

Is there some way to resolve these references automatically to integer IDs, before runtime?

I could store the data in a [typed array](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#TypedArray), but I very much prefer JSON for easy deserialization.

Comment: I don’t think this is a good idea. It’s not a well formed json document you get when you add Android resource references in there.

Comment: If the references could be replaced with the corresponding integer IDs, we'd have well-formed JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If suddenly this is still relevant. In the Json file, you can put the name of the resource you need and find this resource by name.
For example, you have the following `strings.xml`:

```
<resources>
<string name="example_string">Hello, world!</string>
</resources>
```

Your json file will contain the name of the string.
`Sample.json`:

```
{
  "greeting": "example_string"
}
```

All you have to do is find this string in resources by its name:

```
context.getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "string", context.getPackageName());
```